# Fixed width left column, variable width right column

Tags: html, css

Here's a simplified layout of a site:

```
#left_column {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}

<div id="left_column">
</div>

<div id="right_column">
  /* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated */
</div>
```

So as the code implies, I have a left column and a right column. The left column should be 200 pixels wide and go to the bottom of the screen. The right column should take up the rest of the width and will contain a bunch of floated images (kind of like what Google image search looks like). How can I do this with CSS and HTML? I'd rather not use JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a 200px margin to the left edge of the right column, and float the left column.

```
#left_column {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#right_column {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

The 100% height is not going to work the way you think it will work.

Comment: I just want to add that this solution worked for me with multiple fixed columns and a variable right column: float all the columns left *except* the rightmost column, then set the rightmost column's **margin-left** property to the sum of the widths of the other columns (plus a margin).

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="leftcol">Demo text</div>
<div id="rightcol">More demo text</div>
```

​CSS:

```
#leftcol{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#rightcol{
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /*The rest of the browsers support this now*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:200px;
    min-height:2000px;
    background-color:blue;
}
​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ttJfg/1/)

Comment: Not quite right. Your left margin is supposed to be 200px, not 20%.

Comment: Before I found Ariel's solution, I experimented with setting the width of the left column(s) to a fixed value and setting a percentage value for the right column, but that didn't work very well. Up to a point, when the browser window's width is reduced, text in the right column wraps within the column, but after that point (depending on what percentage is used for the right column), the text wraps around to the left side of the page on the next line. If you set **margin-left** for the right column, the always stays within the column. Same behavior in FF, IE, Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/hKyzT/

> HTML

```
<div id="left_column">
    /* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated */
</div>

<div id="right_column">
/* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated *//* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated */
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, #wrapper, #left_column, #right_column { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }


#left_column {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
    border:1px solid green;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#right_column {
  margin-left: 200px; border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: The fiddle appears to be obsolete. There's something totally different there now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the height needs to have a pixel value - percentage values don't seem to increase the height.

```
<style type="text/css">
#left_column {
    width: 20%;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
}
#right_column {
    width:80%;
    float:right;
    background-color:green;
}
div {
    height:1000px;
}
</style>

<div id="left_column">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="right_column">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These solutions didn't quite work for me.  Based on what I read on http://derpturkey.com/two-columns-with-one-fixed-width-and-one-variable-width/, I ended up with something along the lines of this:

```
#right_column {
    margin-left: 200px;
    float: left;
}

#left_column {
    float: left; 
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100%;
}
```